# List all interfaces from a TypeScript project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I need to have compiled in a single file all the interfaces that extends a particular interface for doing some refactoring work (long story). I'm using Visual Studio 2019, but I didn't find any extension that would it for me.

I can create a parser to parse all ts files, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone as already made something that can help me.

Thanks in advance

Alberto

Comment: Visual Studio Code Lens doesn't already show you all of the places that the interface is referenced?

Comment: Yes, it does, but i want not to click every single of the 99+ references, and copy it to a new file (also checking if there are more implementations for every single of these interfaces). Having all of this in a single file could help me study a strategy to refactor them.